# Java hashCode doubt

Tags: java, hashcode

I have this program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {
    private String s;
    public test(String s) { this.s = s; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Object> hs = new HashSet<Object>();
        test ws1 = new test("foo");
        test ws2 = new test("foo");
        String s1 = new String("foo");
        String s2 = new String("foo");
        hs.add(ws1); 
        hs.add(ws2); 
        hs.add(s1); 
        hs.add(s2); // removing this line also gives same output.
        System.out.println(hs.size()); 
    } 
}
```

Note that this is not a homework. We were asked this question on our quiz earlier today. I know the answers but trying to understand why it is so.

The above program gives 3 as output.

Can anyone please explain why that is?

I think (not sure):

The `java.lang.String` class overrides the `hashCode` method from `java.lang.Object`. So the `String` objects with value "foo" will be treated as duplicates. The test class does not override the `hashCode` method and ends up using the `java.lang.Object` version and this version always returns a different hashcode for every object, so the two test objects being added are treated as different.

Comment: your understanding is correct.

Comment: Amir: I've assumed "java.lang.Object version and this version always returns a different hashcode for every object". How can it be true. By piegon hole principle, there can by infinite objects but the hashcode is a limited unsigned int. So two different objects can get same hashcode.

Comment: There can't be infinite objects because you don't have infinite memory; the `Object.hashCode` implementation uses the address that instance is stored at in memory

Comment: From the doc: the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects.

Answer (score 5):

In this case it's not about `hashCode()` but is about `equals()` method. HashSet is still Set, which has semantic of not allowing duplicates. Duplicates are checked for using `equals()` method which in case of String will return `true`

However for your `test` class `equals()` method is not defined and it will use the default implementation from `Object` which will return true only when both references are to the same instance.

Method `hashCode()` is used not to check if objects should be treated as same but as a way to distribute them in collections based on hash functions. It's absolutely possible that for two objects this method will return same value while `equals()` will return false.

P.S. `hashCode` implementation of `Object` doesn't guarantee uniqueness of values. It's easy to check using simple loop.

Comment: "from Object which will return true only when both objects are same" - IMHO, there will be better to say "if references are the same"

Comment: Thank you, I've changed wording

Answer (score 1):

Hashcode is used to narrow down the search result. When we try to insert any key in `HashMap` first it checks whether any other object present with same hashcode and if yes then it checks for the `equals()` method. If two objects are same then `HashMap` will not add that key instead it will replace the old value by new one.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not about overriding the `hashcode()`, it is about `equals` method. Set does not allow duplicates. A duplicate is the one where the objects are logically equal.

For verifying you can try with

```
System.out.println(ws1.equals(ws2));
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

If the objects are equal, only one will be accepted by a set.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few (well quite many) bullets refarding the equals and hashcode from my preparations to SCJP.
Hope it helps:

- equals(), hashCode(), and toString() are public.
- Override toString() so that System.out.println() or other methods can see something useful, like your object's state.
- Use == to determine if two reference variables refer to the same object.
- Use equals() to determine if two objects are meaningfully equivalent.
- If you don't override equals(), your objects won't be useful hashing keys.
- If you don't override equals(), different objects can't be considered equal.
- Strings and wrappers override equals() and make good hashing keys.
- When overriding equals(), use the instanceof operator to be sure you're evaluating an appropriate class.
- When overriding equals(), compare the objects' significant attributes.
- **Highlights** of the equals() contract:

        a. Reflexive: x.equals(x) is true.

     b. Symmetric: If x.equals(y) is true, then y.equals(x) must be true.

     c.  Transitive: If x.equals(y) is true, and y.equals(z) is true, then z.equals(x) is true.

     d. Consistent: Multiple calls to x.equals(y) will return the same result.

      e. Null: If x is not null, then x.equals(null) is false.

     f. If x.equals(y) is true, then x.hashCode() == y.hashCode() is true.
- **If you override equals(), override hashCode().**
- HashMap, HashSet, Hashtable, LinkedHashMap, & LinkedHashSet use hashing.
- An appropriate hashCode() override sticks to the hashCode() contract.
- An efficient hashCode() override distributes keys evenly across its buckets.
- An overridden equals() must be at least as precise as its hashCode() mate.
- To reiterate: if two objects are equal, their hashcodes must be equal.
- It's legal for a hashCode() method to return the same value for all instances (although in practice it's very inefficient).

In addition if you implement equals and hashcode the transient fields (if any) must be treated properly.

The Commons have nice implementation for EqualsBuilder and HashcodeBuilder. They are available in Coomons Lang
http://commons.apache.org/lang/

I use them whenevr I need to implement the equals and the hashcode.